# Buffering GeoJSON with custom CRS in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, buffer, turf, bng

We are using a custom CRS for our map in order to use the British National Grid (EPSG:27700), however we have realised now that `turf.buffer` will not work with it, and appears to only work with Lat/Long (EPSG:4326). What is the best way to buffer shapes when using a custom CRS?

In `L.map` we are setting `crs : L.CRS.BNG` where `L.CRS.BNG` is `L.extend({}, L.CRS.Simple, { options...})`

When using lat/long, for buffering we do: `turf.buffer(geoJson, bufferValue, {units: 'metres'})`

Comment: There should be o problem with this, since standard GeoJSON has coordinates in EPSG:4326 anyway, and Leaflet expects it to be so. Leaflet takes care that GeoJSON vector layer coordinates are converted to map CRS, whatever this CRS is.

Comment: @TomazicM GeoJSON is not EPSG:4326 (lat/long) it's CRS:84 (long/lat)

Comment: @nmtoken Ups, I again forgot that. Thanks! But the main thing remains: turf.js uses lng/lat order, as does the GeoJSON, and Leaflet can handle that. But it's also true that Leaflet uses lat/lng order as coordinate input format to it's methods. Only GeoJSON layer source is expected to have coordinates in standard GeoJSON lng/lat order.

Comment: @TomazicM when using the custom CRS I have the geojson using the coordinates in EPSG:27700, not the standard long/lat. I'm asking how to buffer in this situation.

Comment: Then please edit your question and post more of relevant code (map and layer creation etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reproject](https://github.com/perliedman/reproject) for this task. You will also need to set the custom projection. A good site for the PROJ.4 Defintions is [epsg.io](https://epsg.io).

Here is some sample code using nodejs - (but all libraries are available on the frontend as well):

```
// Dependencies
const { reproject } = require("reproject");
const { WGS84 } = require("proj4");
const turfBuffer = require("@turf/buffer");

// Custom PROJ.4 Definition from https://epsg.io/27700
const customPrj = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs";

// Sample Data in EPSG::27700
const geojson27700 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "sample",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700"
    }
  },
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [424156.793607593746856, 261459.328561440168414],
          [397013.516713735123631, 279715.842466763628181],
          [393190.99559627630515, 260624.890339128091],
          [424156.793607593746856, 261459.328561440168414]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }]
};

// Reproject to EPSG::4326
const geojson4326 = reproject(geojson27700, customPrj, WGS84);

// Create Buffer in EPSG::4326
const geojsonBuffered4326 = turfBuffer(geojson4326, 5000, {units: "metres"});

// Reproject to EPSG::27700
const geojsonBuffererd27700 = reproject(geojsonBuffered4326, WGS84, customPrj);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I went for as I couldn't see a way to do it without this. I used https://github.com/rob-murray/gbify-geojson